# Where to concentrate exactly during meditation?

Tags: meditation

In a chance I had read 'Mindfulness in Plain English' by the Buddhist monk Venerable H.Gunaratana Mahathera.

- It says "After joining inhaling with exhaling,fix your mind on the point where you feel your inhaling and exhaling breath touching.Inhale and exhale as one single breath moving in and out touching or rubbing the rims of your nostrills."
- I have heard  about different meditation practices and I doubt that there is no such a point is drawn in Chakra Meditation.
- Then what is the purpose of concentrating on the rims of the nostrils or  where I have to concentrate during meditation as a beginner?

Comment: Different types of meditation do things differently.  Is your meditation practice tied to a martial art practice? You may want to check out the [Buddhism SE](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meditation) or the [Hinduism SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meditation)  both of which also have meditation tags and deal with the topic in a more broad context.

Comment: I believe that meditation is a crucial part in martial arts.

Comment: I am practicing meditation for better concentration and mindfulness.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because in its current form, it has nothing to do with martial arts. If the meditation was linked to a specific art it might be answerable.

Comment: Don't you know  meditation is strongly connected with Kung-Fu,Kalaripayatu etc.? @Sardathrion

Comment: Are you seeking mediation advise on Kung-Fu or Kalaripayatu or some other martial art? If so, please tag the question appropriately. If your question is about generic meditation, it has no place here. We are expects in martial arts, not meditation.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please do take [the tour](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works. Probably should have said that first. ☺

Comment: Meditation is connected with many, but not all, martial arts.  Different arts use different practices, and many arts contain different meditations which are dissimilar in goals as well.  Without further context, and no tie to a martial arts goal/root, you are really best served by one of the other Stack Exchanges.

Comment: You are asking about Buddhist meditation instructions in terms of Hindu concepts to a group that may have no familiarity with either of these meditative traditions. Each tradition has its own preferred practices and theories for them. Although all meditation may lead to better concentration and mindfulness, you should pick ONE path to follow initially, lest you end up completely lost.